# preg_replace output is not correct

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this example.

```
$link='http://www.mylink.com';
$string= 'You have confirmed your account. <br /> Please click {here} to log in';
echo preg_replace('/(\[(.+)\])/', '<a href="' . $link . '">$2</a>', $string);
```

and the output is:

> You have confirmed your account.  Please click {here} to log in

What is the problem?

Comment: You need `preg_replace('/{(.*?)}/', '<a href="' . $link . '">$1</a>', $string)`. Your  match is inside curly braces, not square brackets. See https://3v4l.org/JOhOh

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thank you so much.
what about  `preg_replace('/(\[(\w*)\])/', '<a href="' . $link . '">$2</a>', $string);` ?

Comment: The same here, but less generic in general, and it has a redundant capturing group around the whole pattern. You do not need that group.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew,  Many thanks, now everything is ok.